# Importing model generated by AutoML Tables to BigQuery ML raises error "Op type not registered 'DecodeProtoSparseV2'"

Tags: tensorflow, google-bigquery, google-cloud-automl

I am trying to import a TensorFlow model generated by AutoML Tables to BigQuery ML.

Unfortunately it gives me the following error

> Op type not registered 'DecodeProtoSparseV2'

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I suggest to add more details on how to reproduce this error.

Comment: Thanks! Actually it was a simple operation. Basically I trained a classification model by using AutoML Tables, and exported the model by using the provided feature. Then I tried to import the model to BigQuery ML by following this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/making-predictions-with-imported-tensorflow-models

Comment: Ok, but consider to add details to your question as comments might be deleted if they are no longer useful. Unfortunately I cannot help you with the question itself.

Comment: There are planned changes to make this way easier! Please stay tuned

Answer (score 2):

<s>Currently, the model exported from AutoML Tables can only run with the provided model server container. See this question: [Loading model generated by AutoML with Tensorflow raises "Op type not registered 'ParseExampleV2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59053918/loading-model-generated-by-automl-with-tensorflow-raises-op-type-not-registered/59060526#59060526) for more detail.</s>

Update: BigQuery ML [now supports AutoML Tables integration](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/release-notes#June_16_2020) (in beta)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I thought it can be imported to BigQueryML, since both of them are product of GCP :D

Comment: `tensorflowjs_convert` fails on the conversion also

Answer (score 0):

Try to install and import struct2tensor

https://pypi.org/project/struct2tensor/