# GCP AutoML Tables predict online takes several seconds

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

The following takes several seconds. I know this is not conceptual but I'm cross posting from a GCP issue just in case someone happened to step on the same scenario.

```js
const { PredictionServiceClient } = require('@google-cloud/automl');
const predictionServiceClient = new PredictionServiceClient({ apiEndpoint });
const prediction = await predictionServiceClient.predict({
    name: modelFullId,
    params,
    payload,
});
```

This API in real time takes close to 10s when cold and 5s when hot. Is there a way to fasten this up other than to export the model and run it yourselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can export the model and use with tensorFlowJS.

https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/edge-quickstart

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-automl

1. Export the model and download `model.json, dict.txt, *.bin` files to your local.
2. Load the model into tensorFlowJS and use it.

Comment: Thanks @Bira, That's what I've been doing. But it defeats the whole _auto_ thing. It's not that automagic anymore

Comment: I am using AWS Lambda to use this prediction. hope it will help you. you may need other aws resources like s3, sqs too

Comment: Where you able to transform the exported model? It seems like they (google) provide a docker image which you can use to run it. But everyone arround is having trouble trying to convert it https://stackoverflow.com/a/59060526/621058